# android background sensor application with dynamic schedule?

Tags: android, android-studio, artificial-intelligence, android-sensors, schedule

The whole project consists in making an android application based on crowd sensing that collects data from volunteers (phase 1) and then based on the collected data, every user has a file in the server and the file would be separated into multiple online episodes and I will apply Artificial intelligence algorithms to make the data mining better.

For example, if in phase 1 I can determine that the volunteer is usually at home before 8am and he has no valuable information for me to analyse then the application wouldn't even send data to the server.
I'm still in phase 1, I'm trying to make an android application that starts running as soon as the user in connected to internet, it would send the data (battery, gps, activity...) to the server and based on the activity (walking, running...) it would determine when the next flow of data is sent. For exemple if he is walking then, the next time the data is sent to the server would be in 5 minutes.

While searching, I found many solutions on how to make an android application run in the background while keeping sensors collecting full time (high energy consumption) and the better solution would be to have a schedule for example every 5 minutes. 
What I want to know is, is there an android studio solution to make the schedule dynamic? because it depends on the activity as I said before, so each time it collects information it schedules the next time the information is collected again (the next time we use sensors to collect the data then send it to the server).

I hope I made my point clear: what is always running in the background is an application that has a countdown to a specific moment; when that moment arrives the sensors are ON to collect data and send it to the server and that data is also used to make the next countdown (based on the activity data collected) and then the sensor are off until the countdown ends.

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best option for your project is [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). It can execute your code periodically or at a particular time, samples could be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).
Also the app could be launched by system state event(like wi-fi on/off). To catch these events you need to use [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), samples are [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html).

So you don't really need to implement countdown timers or background threads. Moreover manually created countdown background thread could be killed by the system at any time.